# Warning: Illegal string offset

Tags: php, session

I'm trying to set session in my program, after the user has logged with his account. If user input good email and password, then program set some variables, like this:

```
$_SESSION['user']['id'] = $row['id'];
$_SESSION['user']['email'] = $email;
$_SESSION['user']['admin'] = $row['admin'];
$_SESSION['logged'] = true;
```

The problem is, that I'm getting this warning from first three rows of code above:

> Warning: Illegal string offset 'id' in C:\Program Files (x86)\Zend\Apache2\htdocs\OOPeshop\user\User.php on line 193

So I checked, if all the variables  are set, so i add to my code this two lines:

```
var_dump($row);
var_dump($email);
```

but it was looking alright, I was getting output

```
array(2) { ["id"]=> string(2) "14" ["admin"]=> string(1) "0"}
```

> string(22) "foobar@gmail.com"

So can someone explain me where is the problem? I checked similar question, but found no solution to my problem.

I have tried this:

```
$user = array('id' => $row['id'], 'email' => $email, 'admin' => $row['admin']);
$_SESSION['user'] = $user;
```

No more warnings. It set array first and then set whole array to session variable, it worked, but i don't know where's problem in my first code, so maybe someone with better understanding can explain it better.

Comment: What happens when you `var_dump($row['id'])`?

Comment: @Steven string(2) "14"

Comment: And `var_dump($_SESSION)`?

Comment: above my code: array(0) { } and below code array(2) { ["user"]=> array(3) { ["id"]=> string(2) "14" ["email"]=> string(22) "foobar@gmail.com" ["admin"]=> string(1) "0" } ["logged"]=> bool(true) }

Comment: Then it doesn't look like there is a problem with this section of code... If there was then the `$_SESSION` variables wouldn't be being set. Are you sure that you're looking at the right lines? What happens if you comment out the lines? (Either that or we have our wires crossed!)

Comment: I commented three lines in question and everything went allright without error...I don't know where's problem with my first code, i will keep it here and maybe someone will come someday and give goog explanation to the problem....until the I will be using my code at the bottom of the question

Comment: Are you getting the warning for all three lines with `$_SESSION['user'][XXX] = XXX`? If so try adding the following line above your code: `unset($_SESSION['user']);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tried this:

```
$user = array('id' => $row['id'], 'email' => $email, 'admin' => $row['admin']);
$_SESSION['user'] = $user;
```

No more warnings. It set array first and then set whole array to session variable, it worked, but i don't know where's problem in my first code, so maybe someone with better understanding can explain it better.

It seems that $_SESSION['user'] has been in somehow set to string, dont know why, but that's the only explanation.

Answer (score 0):

This type of error can be couse of attempt to access an array index using an object or an array as the index key. Check whether your array is proper.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Somewhere in the begininig of your code

```
if(!isset($_SESSION['user'])){
  $_SESSION['user'] = array();
}
```

Then you can continue adding elements for $_SESSION['user'] as you did ( `$_SESSION['user']['id'] = ...` )